# Here it is the program of the printing all the permutation of the string all storing it in the vector but it is printing but not stored why?

Tags: c++, string, stl

Here  i want to store the all the permutation of the string in the vector but its only printing

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<string> str;

void swap(char* x, char* y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
void permute(char* a, int l, int r)
{
    int i;
    if (l == r) {
        cout << a << endl;
        str.push_back(a);
    }

    else {
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            swap((a + l), (a + i));
            permute(a, l + 1, r);
            swap((a + l), (a + i)); //backtrack
        }
    }
}
/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
    char str[] = "ABC";
    int n = strlen(str);
    int l = n;
    permute(str, 0, n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << str[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here in the line no 16 i am storing the string in the vector and in the line 35 and 36
i am trying to print all the permutation again using the loop but its not working
while rest of the code is the working the fine .So help me if i made any mistake.

Comment: A good code indentation is recommended.

Comment: I'd also recommend to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721). Using both is a good way to introduce strange errors.

Answer (score 2):

You defined a `vector<string>` named `str` in global. Then you defined a `char str[]` named `str` as well in `main` function. So in the scope of `main`, invoking `str` corresponds to the `char str[]` but `vector<string>`. Just try to use different variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are accessing `char str[]`, instead of vector `str`.
Avoid using same name for global and local variables.

Answer (score 0):

A Global variable is, as it might sound, a variable that is Global to the code.
That means, you can access it from every scope within the code.

Noticing your code, you have been repeating the variable 'str' both in main and as global.

Conclusion: you should change one of the variable's name.